# DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge for NSURLConnection's SynchronousRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection's sendSynchronousRequest to communicate with server. I wanted to handle authentication which can be achieved using connection delegates but delegates are not called for a synchronous request.

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:UrlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if(!error)
            {

             // Do something
             }
            else
             {
              // Handle error
             }

         });
```

However i thought of sending all the request asynchronously using

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:menuRequest delegate:self];
```

But i have multiple connection in the same class and each connection's success and error are used to perform different task.If i use async request error and success are heard by delegates which are same for all the request in that class, i cannot find out which request failed and which request succeeded. I have two question

1. If there is a way to implement https for synchronous request.
2. How to find which connection failed or succeeded among multiple connections in the same class for asynchronous request.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in different ways.

1. You can put creds in url like `https://username:password@domain.tld/api/user.json`
2. You can add add you creds to `NSURLCredentialStorage` before synchronous connection call.
3. You can use code below to achieve.

   ```
   - (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse *__strong*)response error:(NSError *__strong*)error
   {
      _finishedLoading=NO;
      _receivedData=[NSMutableData new];
      _error=error;
      _response=response;

      NSURLConnection*con=[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:request
                      delegate:self
              startImmediately:NO];
      [con start];

      return _receivedData;
   }


   - (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection  canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
      return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
   }

   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
   {
       //handle the challenge
   }

   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
   {
      *_response=response;
   }

   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
   {
      [_receivedData appendData:data];
   }

   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
      *_error=error;

   }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: Is 3. sending an synchronous request ??? i think it is creating an ansync connetion.

Comment: As per apple documentation if you send `startImmediatly:NO` it schedule ns connection on current run loop by default. If it don't the you can schedule it manually on current thread by `[con scheduleInRunLoop:aRunLoop
                  forMode:mode]` before `[con start];`

Comment: What is the use of using a separate runloop ??. Can i do authentication in sendSynchronousRequest itself.

Comment: Every thread have a runloop. You can schedule your NSURLConnection in multiple run loops. What you wanna do actually can you share your detailed requirements ..?? by using above code you have access to all delegates. What else you require..??

Comment: My basic requirement is Authentication using certificates, i can handle challenges in delegates. My app has three type of requests. 1. Async. 2.Sync 3. InitWithConentsOfUrl. How am i supposed to handle authentication for 2 & 3.

Comment: If you can send me your API with test user I'll send you code for this then we can discuss, how this code is actually working. Sounds good..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72653/discussion-between-vishnuvarthan-and-zahid).